# JavaScript: Dynamically create array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to dynamically create an array from another one in JavaScript.
I have a string which is a mathematical literal expression like this '2a + 3b + 4a + 5c': I just want to split it into an array with only the literal part of the number (Ex. 'a,b,a,c').

I've tried to use the following code to do this :

```
var expression = '2a + 3b + 4a + 5c';
var NumbersArray = expression.split(' + '); /* NumbersArray = 2a,3b,4a,5c */
alert('So far it's working!');
var LettersArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < NumbersArray.length; i++) {
    eval('var LettersArray[' + i + '] = NumbersArray[' + i + '].replace(/[0-9]/g,"");');
    alert(eval('LettersArray[' + i + ']'));
}
```

But it doesn't work!
How can I fix it?

Comment: You've got a syntax error in your first `alert`, the apostrophe needs to be escaped.

Comment: Is it copy-paste error, or are the quotes in your alert actually like that? Because that will cause a syntax error (the apostrophe of `it's` is ending the string). Also, why are you using eval?

Comment: SO code highlighter already provided an answer.

Comment: It was a copy-paste error. In my version the alert's text was not "So far it's working!".

Comment: Wow! Thank you all! I couldn't imagine the power of regular expressions! I' will study them very carefully! Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Lots of errors here, tried to comment all of my fixes:

```
var expression = '2a + 3b + 4a + 5c';
var NumbersArray = expression.split(' + '); /* NumbersArray = 2a,3b,4a,5c */

//using single quotes inside single quotes doesn't work without escaping, try double quotes instead
alert("So far it's working!");

//use array literals [], not new Array() unless you need it
var LettersArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < NumbersArray.length; i++) {
    //why is eval used here? and why are you using var to re-declare LettersArray?
    //eval('var LettersArray[' + i + '] = NumbersArray[' + i + '].replace(/[0-9]/g,"");');
    //alert(eval('LettersArray[' + i + ']'));

    //no need for eval, just access array indexes
    LettersArray[i] = NumbersArray[i].replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
    alert(LettersArray[i]);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FERj5/

A quicker way to accomplish the same thing would be:

```
var expression = '2a + 3b + 4a + 5c';
var letters = expression.replace(/\d+/g, '').split(' + ');
//now letters == ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you all! I couldn't imagine the power of regular expressions! I' will study them very carefully! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

the string in your alert breaks. It should be

```
 alert("So far it's working!");
```

also at eval in your loop same issue is there

this code works

```
var expression = '2a + 3b + 4a + 5c';
var NumbersArray = expression.split(' + '); /* NumbersArray = 2a,3b,4a,5c */
var LettersArray = [];
var evalit;

for (var i = 0; i < NumbersArray.length; i++) {

    evalit = "LettersArray[" + i + "] = NumbersArray[" + i + "].replace(/[0-9]/g,'');";

    eval(evalit);
    alert(LettersArray[i]);
}
```

here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mithunsatheesh/pWBgc/)

also try to avoid `eval` at places where you dont need it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only going to an array from `'2a + 3b + 4a + 5c'` to `'a, b, a, c'` you can make it a lot shorter:

```
var expression = '2a + 3b + 4a + 5c';
expression.replace(/(\d+|\s+)/gi,'').split('+');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using eval. Try this:

```
var expression = '2a + 3b + 4a + 5c';
var NumbersArray = expression.split(' + '); /* NumbersArray = 2a,3b,4a,5c */
var LettersArray = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < NumbersArray.length; i++) {

    LettersArray[i] = NumbersArray[i].replace(/[0-9]/g,"");;
    alert(LettersArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How flexible does this need to be?  If your pattern is always going to be `[number][letter] + [number][letter] + [number][letter] + [number][letter] + ....`, then you could go really basic:

```
var expression = '2a + 3b + 4a + 5c';
var NumbersArray = expression.split(' + '); /* NumbersArray = 2a,3b,4a,5c */
var LettersArray = expression.match(/[a-z]/g); /* LettersArray = a,b,a,c */
```

For a little more flexibility, all you would need to do is change up the regex pattern a little bit:

- If you needed to account for multi-letter variables, you could change
  `/[a-z]/g` to `/[a-z]+/g`.
- If you needed to account for uppercase variables, you could change `/[a-z]/g` to `/[a-z]+/gi`.